# enum singleton, referenced by interface, instance by string name

Tags: java, interface, enums, singleton

Thanks for viewing my question, which I have not successfully found an answer for in my searches/books. I'm learning java by writing a roguelike, but I think this question is more java-related than game-related. Feel free to educate me if I'm wrong.

I have similar classes that I want to each have specific abilities. The abilities are enum singletons with a set of standard method names that I would pass the Actor to - I wanted to avoid implementing methods from an interface in every Actor class, and just really liked the envisioned use of this approach as I go forward. I come from a shell/perl background and can't tell if I'm just not thinking OOP, or if I'm on to something useful and don't have the skills yet to pull it off.

addAbility(String) in StdActor is where it finally broke in this experiment.

Question is - am I doing something wrongheaded here?  If not, how could I implement this?

interface for manipulating abilities:

```
public interface ActorAbility {

    // doesn't work, but need something to enable
    // instance retrieval for addAbility...
    public ActorAbility getInstance();

    public void act(Actor actor);

    public boolean isTickable();

}
```

sanitized implementation of interface:

```
public enum ActorMove implements ActorAbility {
    INSTANCE;

    private ActorMove() {
    }

    public ActorAbility getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public void act(Actor actor) {
        log.debug("Move");
    }

    public boolean isTickable() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

sanitized use of the ability.  trial and error run amock.  addAbility(String) broken, copy/paste from SO and elsewhere. it probably needs to be nuked from orbit.

```
public class StdActor implements Actor {
    private HashSet<ActorAbility> abilities = new HashSet<>();

    // this whole method is wrecked
    public void addAbility(String ability) {
        // Class<? extends ActorAbility> action;  // in a maze of twisty passages...
        ActorAbility actionInstance = null;
        try {
            // action = Class.forName("game3.Actors.Abilities." + ability);
            actionInstance = ActorAbility.valueOf("game3.Actors.Abilities."
                + ability);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.abilities.add(actionInstance);
    }
}
```

use case:

```
public class StdCharClass extends StdActor {

    public StdCharClass() {
        // I like this because it's clean and easily
        // changeable
        addAbility("ActorMove");
    }
}
```

future planned use:

```
HashSet<ActorAbility> abilities = actor.getAbilities();
for (ActorAbility ability : abilities) {
    if (ability.isTickable()) {
        ability.act(actor);
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks for such a quick comment, JB.  I tried what you suggested and it appears to do what I was hoping.  It appears I was just off in the weeds and needed to be pulled back.

Comment: Your getInstance() method doesn't make much sense: you need to have the instance to be able to call getInstance(), which would return itself. Why do you use one enum per ability, instead of a single enum listing all the abilities? Why use strings to represent abilities rather then the enum instances: `addAbility(Ability.MOVE)`. That would make everything type-safe.

Comment: *"addAbility(String) in StdActor is where it finally broke in this experiment."* What's the problem exactly? What happened?

Comment: @Pshemo: I never post here so thank you for the link - it is a helpful reference.  I edited my question to include an implementation of the solution proposed by JB Nizet.  As reputation can be awarded in the "Answer" case, I was offering that courtesy as I thought it was due.  I intended to wait a reasonable amount of time to allow JB to post in answer form before creating/accepting the answer myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new class:

```
public enum Ability {
    MOVE(ActorMove.INSTANCE), FIGHT(ActorFight.INSTANCE);

    private ActorAbility ability;

    private Ability(ActorAbility abilityClass) {
        this.ability = abilityClass;
    }

    public ActorAbility getAbility() {
        return this.ability;
    }
}
```

StdActor:

```
public class StdActor implements Actor {
private HashSet<Ability> abilities = new HashSet<>();

public void addAbility(Ability ability) {
    this.abilities.add(ability);
}
```

subclass:

```
public class StdCharClass extends StdActor {

    public StdCharClass() {
        addAbility(Ability.MOVE);
    }

}
```

and finally, usage:

```
HashSet<Ability> abilities = bob.getAbilities();
for (Ability ability : abilities) {
    ActorAbility abilityClass = ability.getAbility();
    if (abilityClass.isTickable()) {
        abilityClass.act(bob);
    }
}
```

output!

```
12:44:15.835 [main] DEBUG ActorMove - Move
```